# Why HTML with disabled CSS matters?

Tags: html, css

When creating a website why should you care for HTML with no style?

Is there any device which will render HTML only (no CSS or JavaScript)?

**Do you usually care how your website will display without CSS?**

**Why is it important?**

Comment: It's entirely up to you, you could build a website with no css styling. In my opinion you should dive into html and css at around the same time if you're learning. It's good front end experience.

Comment: think screen-readers.. not for *visibility* but for ***semantics***

Comment: @Supplement thnks for the answer, i'm not learning, i work with it everyday,,lool,, i am just wondering whether html with no style should be well displayed (talking about content) or not.

Comment: It's impossible to be a web worker and not learn something new everyday =)

Comment: @owzim Of course, i am learning everyday, what i mean is i am not starting to learn html and css, so he could better understand my question. And i am asking this so i can learn more, that's why i am here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be a few misconceptions here. First of all and most importantly, screenreaders **do** take into account CSS and JavaScript. Why? Simply because unlike in the past they are not running on their own, but rather work as addons for existing browsers or include the render engines inline in their own systems.

Does that mean you don't need to concern yourself with screenreaders at all? Sadly that's not the case either. For example, if you add `display:table` to an element just because you want to vertically align something some screenreaders will actually treat it like a real table (which makes no practical sense). The good part is though that pages are read top-to-bottom, header and menu first (if found) and that adding `display:none` through javascript to an element will hide the element from the screen reader as well. Now, the following is going to sound really harsh, but except if you're making a *real* high profile website I wouldn't advice you to concern yourself with this too much. On one hand screenreaders are becoming better and better (try for example the one that's included on your android device if you have a recent version of android) and on the other hand blind people are used to websites being a 'bit' messy. Now, that doesn't mean you should start using flash or otherwise crazy stuff, but it does mean that if you just write a proper website, make your menu a list, make your divisions divs and not tables etc. you should in general be fine. And if you *are* making a high profile website then you should check out [WAI-ARIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAI-ARIA).

Now, getting to the search engine part, that's not true either for the big search engines at least. Google *does* take styling into account. Not all the styling that's unimportant for Google, but it actually will realize which stuff is hidden and analyzes the javascript whether hidden content will be shown (as part of it's anti-SEO work), it will search for links in your javascript and probably lots more I am not aware of. Bing does this to a large extend as well, though for example duckduckgo does not do this too much/at all. Either way, once again, the notion that Google sees your site like lynx does was true in the far past, but by now is invalid.

And if you check your serverlogs you will see that *nobody* accessed your site through lynx. That's just the reality of life nowadays. In the past (again) people would occasionally use lynx if they only had access to a console, but nowadays it's far easier to pull your phone from your pocket which runs a full web browser.

Comment: Yeah, i knew that somehow, nowadays it's almost impossible for your website not to be associated to a css, if it isn't that would be a rare case.
Also i think i should take into account the public i'm aiming at, let's say i'm building my website, which i am, lol, i think that wouldn't matter so much since i already know who i'm aiming at.
So knowing my public i don't need to bother so much about accessibility.
Also google search, twitter, facebook are big websites which almost everyone in the world uses, so they had to make it accessible to every one.

Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 5):

There are several cases in which websites may be used without styling. As mentioned in the comments, screen readers (such as those used by visually-impaired people) read only content, not styling.

Perhaps more importantly, many search engine spiders (think: Google) read your site without styling. When you view your site without CSS, you will gain a better understanding of how search engines view your content.

And if you are lucky, or your content is particularly geeky, you may get the occasional guru who browses your site via [Lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/).

Comment: Lynx... is it that telnet client that strips all HTML from the response before displaying it? :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak It is a text-based browser. HTML markup is retained, but graphics and most colors (except text colors) are removed.

Comment: +1 Yes, for these reasons, the hierarchy and structure of your HTML matter. It's part of the "progressive enhancement" and "graceful degradation" approaches to web development/design. Similar reasons for providing (as best you can) non-javascript alternatives to interacting with your content.

Comment: I'd add older browsers to this. Some read *SOME* styles but certainly not CSS3 standards. Some don't read any at all.

Answer (score 1):

First part of the answer : 'text based browsers'

[Text-based browser list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers)

```
Alynx
ELinks (active version of Links)
Emacs/W3
Line Mode Browser
Links
Lynx
Net-Tamer
w3m
WebbIE
```

Second part : 'search engines'

[List of semantic search engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_semantic_search_engines)

[List of search engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_search_engines)

Third part : '[web accessibility](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/accessibility.php)' where software helps [people with disabilities get access to the web.](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/people-use-web/Overview.html)

> It's important to note that for the third part, accessibility, it is
>   sometimes a legal requirement. For example, in the UK it is illegal to
>   have a website that is not accessible to blind people. There are
>   similar requirements for US government services. – [slebetman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/167735/slebetman)

It's also an applicable [law in canada](http://www.tbs-sct.gc.ca/pol/doc-eng.aspx?id=23601&section=text)

See this [list of tools from w3](http://www.w3.org/WAI/RC/tools/complete) for a Complete List of Web Accessibility Evaluation Tools

Comment: It's important to note that for the third part, accessibility, it is sometimes a legal requirement. For example, in the UK it is illegal to have a website that is not accessible to blind people. There are similar requirements for US government services.

Answer (score 0):

CSS isn’t an on/off thing. Although CSS *may* be completely disabled, it is much more common that *some* of your CSS settings get ignored or overridden. Here is an incomplete list of cases (see my [CSS Caveats](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/css-caveats.html) for some additional details):

- Speech-based browsers generally ignore most of CSS, largely because most of CSS is directed towards visual rendering.
- So do “text-only browsers” (more accurately, character cell browsers, which render in plain text only using a monospace font but may be able to use colors and bolding).
- Search engines generally don’t care about CSS at all.
- CSS support varies. The more advanced CSS features you use, the more probable it is that many browsers don’t implement them.
- CSS support may be disabled by the user, completely or partially.
- User style sheets may interfere with your CSS code or even override them.
- Browser settings e.g. on minimum font size may make some of you CSS settings ineffective.
- Browsers have bugs. The more complicated CSS techniques you use, the more probable it is that you trigger a bug in some browsers.
- An external CSS file (the recommended way of using CSS) may get lost, e.g. a browser may need to wait (perhaps in vain) from a server, or an archiving system may archive an HTML file but fail to archive the CSS file.
- Styling may get lost in transfer, e.g. when copying content from a web page to MS Word or Excel or Notepad or email.